# Are these expressions still relevant?

Tags: archaic-language

Are the following expressions in bold still relevant?

1. **"made good spare of"**

   > But then againe ther arose Strong and Great Windes from the South, with a Point East ; which carried us up, (for all that we could doe) towards the North : By which time our Victualls failed us, though we had **made good spare of** them. So that finding ourselves, in the Midst of the greatest Wildernesse of Waters in the World, without Victuall, we gave our Selves for lost Men, and prepared for Death.

   — Francis Bacon, *New Atlantis* (1627)
2. **"can make choice of"**

   > *Kent*. I thought the king had more affected the Duke of Albany than Cornwall.
   >   　*Glo.* It did always seem so to us; but now, in the division of the kingdom, it appears not which of the dukes he values most, for equalities are so weighed that curiosity in neither **can make choice of** either's moiety.

   — William Shakespeare, *King Lear* (1606)

Have they already fallen into expiry?

Comment: "Respectively" means you are referring to one expression from Shakespeare, and one from Bacon. Which is which? I would think that if your everyday language includes sentences like "fallen into expiry", you can certainly make use of the sentence that you are questioning - it feels about as old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only uses of *make/made/making spare of* I can find on Google Books date from the 17th century, except for one historical novel which is set in that century.

*Make choice of* lasted longer, but has been in steady decline for three hundred years. It seems always to have had a formal ring, and by 1900 it appears almost entirely in legal and theological contexts. I think it may be regarded today as a curious fossil.

Comment: The *reasons* for the respective declines are different though. On the semantic level, ***spare** = [the exercise of] frugality*, has been pretty much consigned to the dustbin of linguistic history, but all that's happened with ***choice*** is that for the last century and more we've discarded the old "article-less" syntax in favour of *make **a** choice*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right - but as *make choice of* was actually used I think in most cases we're replaced it with the verb *choose*.

Comment: I'm not too hot on using arithmetical expressions in NGrams, but I *think* [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(make+a+choice+between)%2F(choose+between)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28make%20a%20choice%20between%29%20/%20%28choose%20between%29%3B%2Cc0) is telling us that the ratio between ***make a choice between*** and ***choose between*** has remained relatively constant for a couple of centuries. The big change is that *make choice* with no article has practically vanished.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm speaking of *make choice **of** X* versus *choose X*. ***A** choice* was never in play in that context: see [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+choice+of%2Fchoose%2Cmade+choice+of%2Fchose%2Cmake+a+choice+of%2Fchoose%2Cmade+a+choice+of%2Fchose&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28make%20choice%20of%20/%20choose%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28made%20choice%20of%20/%20chose%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28make%20a%20choice%20of%20/%20choose%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28made%20a%20choice%20of%20/%20chose%29%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Well you'll obviously be more familiar with the exact "parsing" of Shakespeare's usage there. But to me it seems at least as much reminiscent of *make a meaningful choice [as to which "half" is better]* as it is of *meaningfully choose [which is better]*. I freely admit I find it hard to distinguish whether/how much of the sense is *choose A or B* (emphasis on the act of choosing?) as opposed to *make a choice* (emphasis on which is or may be chosen?).

Comment: Totally unrelated, but might you want to have a look at answering [Tense agreement in the past irrealis conditionals](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24463/tense-agreement-in-the-past-irrealis-conditionals)?

Comment: @FumbleFingers In the *KL* chunk, "...the most precise analysis cannot choose either's portion [implicit: as more valuable than the other's]." *Make choice of* is consistently used in the 17th and 18th centuries with the person or thing chosen as the object of the preposition, not the set from which the choice is selected.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The tense question is *hors de concours* for me - I strictly avoid questions with bounties, lest I appear greedy. But I suggest that the *now*, which seems to be the core problem, is very precisely addressed in your own comment to [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/my-understanding-of-could#comment49024_26363)

Comment: I sense what we're really lacking here is *Canonical Post #3: How do modal verbs work in relation to irrealis states?* In [which](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26397/126) context I will simply say that I'd virtually forgotten about ***irrealis***, which just seemed like obscure Lit Crit "jargon" to me when I was at college, but now I've seen you use it so often here it seems like a perfectly natural term. That's to say, I consider it to be (one of) your specialist subjects.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Groan! It's a very short and very unsatisfactory Post: "In maddeningly unpredictable ways"! But I can't yet bring myself to say that to zealous and discerning students like Zhanlong Zheng.

Comment: Seconded! Particularly in relation to modals and "verb tenses as they relate to time/conditionality" it seems to me Zhanlong has a tendency to ask about things that push at/go beyond the bounds of precision as supported by our language. I've long thought it's almost "deliberate" that English gets a bit fuzzy in the general area of possibility / requests / deference, partly so that people can *think* they're of like mind even when they're actually *not*.

Answer (score 2):

Both usages are effectively obsolete. OED doesn't specifically say that...

> ***spare*** *- the exercise of economy, frugality, or moderation.
>
>   Chiefly in the phrase to **make (no, etc.) spare***.

...is archaic or obsolete, but their last citation for the usage is 1891, so draw your own conclusion.

The last citation for ***to make choice of*** = to choose, select is 1887, but that's under a definition which also includes *to make **a** choice of*. The most recent citation *without* an article is 1660.

---

Related usages which *are* still in common use include *make [good] **use** of, make **fun** of, make **light** of*. Variants which are "dated, but not excessively so" include *make **sport** of*.