# Mixed conditionals/ 3rd conditional which one should be the better option to go with?

Tags: conditional-constructions

If I hadn't left her, it **would be** our 7th anniversary tomorrow.

If I hadn't left her, It **would have been**  our 7th anniversary tomorrow.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct?
Do they mean the same?
What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: I'd use *have been* only if the thing is over. So, if it's tomorrow, I'd use *would be...*

Answer (score 5):

It's true that "it would be / would have been our 7th anniversary tomorrow" is about the future, and many speakers, particularly strict teachers and non-native speakers, would think that *"If I hadn't left her, it **would have been** our 7th anniversary tomorrow."* sounds wrong or even ungrammatical because it's "tomorrow" and tomorrow hasn't come yet.

However, this appears to be acceptable and I think it happens often enough that we shouldn't consider it ungrammatical. *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan addresses this in 259.3:

> **259 if (4):** unreal past situations
>   **3 present use: situations that are no longer possible**
>
> We sometimes use structures with *would have ...* to talk about present and future situations which are no longer possible because of the way things have turned out.
>   　　　　*It **would have been** nice to go to Australia this winter, but there's no way we can do it.* (OR *It would be nice ...*)
>   　　　　*If my mother hadn't knocked my father off his bicycle thirty years ago, I **wouldn't have been** here now.* (OR *... I wouldn't be here now.*)

To put it simply, both of your alternatives should be equally acceptable. Just keep in mind that on exams (or in exams, if you prefer *in* to *on*), it's probably safer to use *it would be our 7th anniversary tomorrow*.

Comment: A crystal clear explanation. One more gap in grammar has been filled.

Comment: Consider ordinary English sentences: *I was going to have lunch with him tomorrow,  but I got sick.* *She was to become famous the next year.* *Marty said that he wanted to become president*. A good teacher or text should make it clear that a past tense form does not always mean we are talking about the past. I wouldn't proscribe this usage on a formal test, it is formal English.

Comment: -1 The sentence you are talking about is the model way to construct the so-called third conditional. This answer explains the use of tomorrow, but the OP is not asking about the use of *tomorrow*, but about the difference between a mixed conditional and the third conditional. The use of *tomorrow* in the third conditional poses no problem to native speakers, as past tense forms are often used to refer to future time. This is how English works.

Comment: *I thought that if Joe arrived yesterday, **John arrived tomorrow**, but I was wrong*. This is the way English works. This is reported speech and the backshift to *arrived tomorrow* is perfect natural, normal, standard, and exam-worthy English.

Comment: "The sentence you are talking about is the model way to construct the so-called third conditional. This answer explains the use of tomorrow" that's a very confusing way to start a comment, I believe, considering that "The sentence you are talking about" and "This answer" should be about the same thing. If you want to discuss some minor points, I'd like to recommend you improve your comments, make your thought more organized and explain it a little clearer. If you find that a bit inconvenient (I know that writing clearly takes time) you can find me in a chat room (either is fine).

Comment: *If I hadn't left her, it would have been our 7th anniversary tomorrow* uses textbook English, literally, regarding the verb tenses of the 3rd conditional. See [A university grammar: 3rd ed](https://books.google.com/books?id=vdrfBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263&dq="open+conditional"+English&source=bl&ots=7aqL66Ja50&sig=-E_NY8onsIVKrOCJ2nRf2FOOsOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5_em9ezMAhWMaD4KHS-9Ci04ChDoAQgZMAA#v=snippet&q=conditional%20&f=false) (34.3.3, page 265). The concluding sentence of your answer is unfortunate, because it advises learners not to use the textbook way to form the 3rd  conditional.

Comment: @AlanCarmack You textbook is rather unique and if I'm not mistaken it approaches conditionals differently from other books which are more typical to English learners. (For example, on page 24, it writes "*This coffee is better than any I have ever tasted.* (comparative, non-factual); *If you want any more coffee, you must make it yourself.* (conditional, non-factual)".) The book also doesn't use the term "third/3rd conditional" (I've tried searching for it in the book). The examples by the OP are clear to me that this is a typical side-effect of the 3rd conditional explained in a typical book.

Comment: @AlanCarmack It turns out, the book is not that different from other books. On page 256 (I missed this the first time because your link doesn't jump right to that page), it states: "In this type [counterfactual conditional, aka the 3rd conditional] the even or state is presented as counter to the reality: it didn't happen." Note the word "didn't". (It's not "doesn't", or "won't".) This is a typical explanation of the 3rd conditional in grammar books for learners.

Comment: @AlanCarmack BTW, I don't use these 0, 1, 2, 3, or mixed conditionals myself, but thanks anyway. Personally, these conditionals are the first thing I'd advise a learner to abandon as soon as possible if they asked for my advice. :-)

Comment: It works the same as *It would have been a pleasure to have met your son tomorrow* (but we didn't).

Answer (score 2):

Both the hypothetical, counterfactual sentences are correct grammatically, with a little difference in meaning.

The first tense is a mixture of conditional type II and conditional type III.  The if-clause refers to the condition in the past, whereas the 
main clause refers to the result in the future. In simple words, as said by Khan,  it implies that I really left her. So it won't be our 7th anniversary tomorrow.

On the other hand, the second sentence is conditional type III, in which we talk about the situation both in the if-clause and the main clause in the past. Because of the use of 'tomorrow' in the main clause, 'would have' refers to the future from the point of view of the past.  This sentence in actuality means that I left her. So we didn't have our 7th anniversary the next day.

The use of these sentences depends on the time frame you have in your mind in regard to the anniversay.  If you want to refer to the happening of the anniversary in the future, you should use would be.  On the other hand, if you want to refer to the happening of the event in the future from the point of view of the past, you should use would have been.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both sentences are grammatically correct.

They both mean that the speaker really did leave "her" in the past, but if the contrary were true, the speaker and "her" (*ie* she) would be celebrating their 7th anniversary on the day after the speaker utters this sentence (which day is *tomorrow*).

Notice, first, that this is a past unreal condition. Different folks call it different things; you call it a third conditional; the textbook *[English Grammar: A University Course](https://books.google.com/books?id=vdrfBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263&dq=%22open%20conditional%22%20English&source=bl&ots=7aqL66Ja50&sig=-E_NY8onsIVKrOCJ2nRf2FOOsOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5_em9ezMAhWMaD4KHS-9Ci04ChDoAQgZMAA#v=snippet&q=conditional%20&f=false)* (3rd edition) calls it a "counterfactual conditional clause"). Click on Page 265 of that link.

As for which version (*would be* or *would have been*) should be the better option to go with, it really depends on what you want to say. Note that page 266 of the same textbook says

> The counterfactual construction [would/should/could + have + past participle of full verb]...can occur in other discourse contexts such as expressing regret or reproof at something that didn't take place.

and gives the example

> It would have been a pleasure to meet your son. (but we didn't meet him)

This same sense of expressing regret or lament over something that didn't take place  is one reason you might choose *would have been* in your sentence. If you did not want to express this, you should choose *would be*.

As for the word *tomorrow* in the main clause of a past unreal conditional, it's  working the same way as in

> If we had had the opportunity, it **would have been** a pleasure to meet your son *tomorrow* when **we were** all in Phoenix *tomorrow*, but I doubt I'll be over the plague by *tomorrow* and will need to stay in my room *tomorrow*. Thus my being sick prevents such a meeting *tomorrow*.

The whole (conditional)  sentence is written about the future–from the point of the past.  We often do this in English, as in

> I *was going* to meet your son tomorrow, but I got sick

and

> Tomorrow *was going* to be our 7th anniversary, but I left her.

Comment: You need to point out that *hadn't've* is a recent innovation (a new "subjunctive" suffix, *-da*, negative *-dna*) which has become common in colloquial English but is still entirely unacceptable in formal English.

Comment: You may ignore the bit about a 'new subjunctive suffix', but the fact stands that *If I had not have left* is not Standard English.

Comment: On reading this answer I've got a feeling of gnawing doubt: Could I have missed anything so significant in  English grammar? If anywhere, where can one have your point  elucidated - a grammar book or a link to the information?

Comment: Quite so; indeed, I myself use this very often in speech. But it will be rejected in most academic contexts; and I think we owe it to our learners (many of whom are pursuing or hope to pursue advanced degrees in Anglophone universities) to make them aware of these differences in register.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but the part *If I hadn't've left her, ...* is probably too "real" for me! (BTW, not my downvote.)

Comment: @Rompey Which point?

Comment: Sorry, I was just wondering if you might add a link to the resource you'd been using answering the question.

Comment: @Rompey One such resource is  *[A university grammar: 3rd ed](https://books.google.com/books?id=vdrfBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263&dq="open+conditional"+English&source=bl&ots=7aqL66Ja50&sig=-E_NY8onsIVKrOCJ2nRf2FOOsOg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio5_em9ezMAhWMaD4KHS-9Ci04ChDoAQgZMAA#v=snippet&q=conditional%20&f=false)* (34.3.3, page 265). I will add the link next time I edit this answer.

Comment: @StoneyB, Alan, But some things that need tweaking: "invert the protasis", "were I not to invert the clauses", "present perfect aspect in the apodosis". You might consider tweaking "the present psychological relevance"<-- If we already understand what you mean, then it's easy to understand what this refers to. But if we don't it's impossible to decipher what this means, imo.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: I've got the book now and on close perusal can say, "close but no cigar".  In para 34.3.3."Counterfactual conditional clauses" it is said that  the structure of the counterfactual clause has If+a past perfect in the conditional clause and a modal perfect (would+have+past participle of the lexical (!!!) verb) in the main clause. And there's nothing more to it - it still doesn't explain why "it would have been" ("be" being an auxiliary verb) can refer to the future ("tomorrow" in the sentence). Thanks, for the book though. The best

Comment: @Rompey (1) *To be* can function both as an auxiliary verb (when it is followed by another verb) or as a full or lexical verb (see [linguapress](http://linguapress.com/grammar/to-be.htm) for example). (2) The OP does not ask why *would have been* can refer to the future, or question the use of *tomorrow* in either sentence. I am answering the question the OP asks (the difference in the two sentences), not questions he or she doesn't ask.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: Thanks again -- this time for the link to the site,  so far unknown to me. You've been most helpful, really.

Comment: @AlanCarmack One important point that this question seems to stem from (IMHO) is that in most, if not all, grammar books for learners explains the 3rd conditional as a pattern used for something that didn't happened, and the standard pattern of this conditional is *If X had(n't) happened, Y would(n't) have happened*. IMHO, it's fair to argue that most books don't address *If X had(n't) happened, Y would(n't) have happened tomorrow* (but what could we expect from standard books?).

Comment: (con't) In reality, the explanation implies that *..., Y would(n't) have happened tomorrow* isn't good because "tomorrow" is not something that "didn't happen" (in other words, it hasn't happened yet). If you noticed, I think it's quite clear that everyone in comments and answers (and likely, the OP as well), except native speakers (and me) feels like using *would have been* in the OP's example is not quite as acceptable as *have been* (again, because it's "tomorrow").

Comment: @Damkering: Having said that (most books don't address that), could you please mention at least one that does? I do want to read it with my own eyes, and I'll do the best I can to get the book.

Comment: @Rompey I was just hedging! :) Actually, I haven't found one! -- BTW, *Practical English Usage* (Michael Swan), though mentions these conditionals briefly, also states: "These [conditionals] are useful structures to practise. However, students sometimes think that these are the only possibilities, and become confused when they meet sentences like *If she didn't phone this morning, then she's probably away* ('What's this? A fourth conditional?'). ..."

Comment: @DamkerngT. and Rompey I understand that some learners might view the string *would(n't) have happened tomorrow* as problematic. But I do not read this question as asking about the use of 'tomorrow' in either sentence. (Indeed, we might ask why is 'tomorrow' acceptable in *would be tomorrow*.) I think the question as to *why* or *how* such words as 'tomorrow' are acceptable in such a string would make a good question to ask here on ELL, if it hasn't been asked before. My comments, spread throughout this page, hint as to why.

Comment: @AlanCarmack I think I understand your point, but asking "which one should be the better option to go with?" and including "tomorrow" in the examples are strong clues to the the confusion of or the preference for *would be ... tomorrow* (as opposed to *would have been ... tomorrow*, which is basically the only difference in the examples), and this is directly related to the 3rd conditional as taught in typical grammar books. I think your answer is good at explaining how a native speaker would think when they selected these alternatives, but you overlook the likely root cause of the problem.

Comment: AlanCarmack: It's "it would have been...tomorrow" in the main and  "If+a past perfect (even be it in negative)" in the conditional clause that coursed all this debate. I would, actually I already did, accept: "If he hadn't been killed in a car accident two years ago, he might have lived to his centenary in 2018.  Anyway, he would have been alive now and a few yeas to go." At the same time, for me, to accept the second example sentense as a correct one, there needs to be a written authoritative word.

Comment: AlanCarmack: You said you're editing your answer, and it's great! I understand that in the limits the answer allows, it's close to impossible to cover the whole theme, so I'm going to put a more specific question in a new thread, depending on what I have read in the edited answer -- unless someone else does it sooner than I do. The theme seems to be inexhaustible. .

Comment: +1 (I still like the explanation based on your intuition in first revisions better, though. Personally, I think it was better than the book.)

Comment: @DamkerngT Heh. Thanks. I'm still trying to define past unreal conditional so that the use of a future adverbial does not seem remarkable (which of course it does not to native speakers). Both *yesterday* or *tomorrow* could work in the past unreal conditional sentence.